# subtracting strings in array of data python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, pandas, loops

I am trying to do the following:

1. create an array of random data
2. create an array of predefined codes (AW, SS)
3. subtract all numbers as well as any instance of predefined code.
4. if a string called "HL" remains after step 3, remove that as well and take the next alphabet pair. If a string called "HL" is the ONLY string in the array then take that.

I do not know how to go about completing steps 3 - 4.

## 1.

```
array_data = ['HL22','PG1234-332HL','1334-SF-21HL','HL43--222PG','HL222AW11144RH','HLSSDD','SSDD']
```

## 2.

```
predefined_code = ['AW','SS']
```

## 3.

ideally, results for this step will look like

```
result_data = [['HL'],['PG,HL'],['SF','HL'],['HL','PG'],['HL','RH'], 
['HL','DD'],['DD']
```

## 4. ideally, results for this step will look like this:

```
result_data = [['HL'],['PG'],['SF'],['PG'],['RH'], ['DD'],['DD']
```

for step 3, I have tried the following code

```
not_in_predefined = [item for item in array_data if item not in predefined_code]
```

but this doesnt produce the result im looking for, because it it checking item against item. not a partial string match.

Comment: Step 3 is pretty much where actual coding begins. What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated post thank you

Comment: Sorry, what is difference with [this your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52773492/2901002) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple using Regex.

`re.findall(r'[A-Z].',item)` should give you the text from your strings, and then you can do the required processing on that.

You may want to convert the list to a set eventually and use the `difference` operation, instead of looping and removing the elements defined in the `predefined_code` list.